# MySQL LEFT JOIN with WHERE returns NULL

Tags: mysql

Trying to JOIN a few tables to supply the user some information on other users he subscribed to this session.
There is a list of other users with their pictures

this works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT profile_picupload.imageFull, goals_list.goal, goal03.other, 
users.username, users.email  FROM profile_picupload 
JOIN anal_muses 
ON anal_muses.username = profile_picupload.username 
JOIN goal03 ON goal03.username = anal_muses.username 
JOIN goals_list ON goal03.goal=goals_list.id 
JOIN users ON users.email = anal_muses.username
```

it gives me the desired list.

But - i need the list from anal_muses for this session only - so i changed the code to this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT profile_picupload.imageFull, goals_list.goal, goal03.other,
users.username, users.email  FROM profile_picupload 
right  JOIN anal_muses 
ON anal_muses.username = profile_picupload.username 
AND  anal_muses.sessionId='$sessionId'
JOIN goal03 ON goal03.username = anal_muses.username 
JOIN goals_list ON goal03.goal=goals_list.id 
JOIN users ON users.email = anal_muses.username
```

table profile_picupload - holds only one picture for each user
while table anal_musers holds many rows for each user ( depends on the number of people he subscribed to)
so when i added AND  anal_muses.sessionId='$sessionId' I needed to change the first join to RIGHT JOIN

but now i get a list with NULL values for profile_picupload .imageFull
.....

is there a way around this?

Thank you :-)

Comment: `RIGHT JOIN` means that it should return rows from `anal_muses` that don't have any match in `profile_picupload`, and put `NULL` in those columns. That's the difference between `JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN`.

Comment: So the question is.. why do you need the "Outer" join?

Comment: I do get profile_picupload.imageFull until i added: AND  anal_muses.sessionId='$sessionId'....

Comment: @Barmar - Thank you - see my previous comment. Null existed for some of my content (Distinct got me the complete data i wanted for some reason....) only when i added the extra AND ..... I have the same results without imageFull fiels

Comment: @xQbert :-) - I'm not sure what you mean by "Outer" :-). The other JOINs were to get more relevant data. When I run the query without them the problem remains.. Everything is fine without: AND anal_muses.sessionId='$sessionId'

Comment: Please post some sample contents of the tables, and the result you're trying to get.

Comment: Understanding table Joins: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/   I believe the null values are occurring because of your "OUTER" right join.  You're saying as @Barmar points out, you want all records from anal_muses if they have no records in profile_picupload, then you'll get nulls.  Remove the `right` leaving `join` and the nulls go away.